# How to pass Get-ADComputers into Invoke-Command in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am listing ad computers in couple of OUs then run `Invoke-Command` on each of them, but somehow, it wont pass the result from `Get-ADComputer` into `Invoke-Command`. What am I doing wrong? It only results the first PC found in the first OU.

```
$DesktopOUs = 'OU=aaa,DC=aaa,DC=com',
              'OU=bbb,DC=aaa,DC=com'
$PCName =  $DesktopOUs | foreach {
    Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties * -SearchBase $_ |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pcname -ScriptBlock {
    $win7kb = "*KB4025341*"

    $Session = New-Object -ComObject "Microsoft.Update.Session"
    $Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()
    $historyCount = $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()
    $Searcher.QueryHistory(0, $historyCount) |
        Where-Object {$_.title -like $win7kb} | 
        Select-Object Date,
            @{name="Operation"; expression={switch($_.operation){1 {"Installation"}; 2 {"Uninstallation"}; 3 {"Other"}}}},
            @{name="Status"; expression={switch($_.resultcode){1 {"In Progress"}; 2 {"Succeeded"}; 3 {"Succeeded With Errors"}; 4 {"Failed"}; 5 {"Aborted"}}}},
            Title
} | Out-GridView -Title "Win7"
```

Comment: You use `$PCName` to store the output from `Get-ADComputer`, but refer to `$name` when using `Invoke-Command`. Also, the `-Properties *` parameter argument is unnecessary and will incur you some overhead

Comment: `$PCName | % {  Invoke-Command -computername $_ -scriptblock {...} }` etc... - also `Out-GridView` will not work, you should save the output from the `Invoke-Command`, then pipe it to `Out-GridView` locally

Comment: @Avshalom That was my first attempt `$PCName | % { Invoke-Command -computername $_ -scriptblock {...} }` and it got the same result. only list the first PC found in first OU

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen i changed the $name to $pcname after i pasted my code to here. missed one spot.  it is consistent on my computer.

Comment: @RootLoop that's not logical, see my answer with example, if your $PCName contains all the computers, the invoke-command should not care what in it, and will run all of them

Answer (score 1):

with a few changes to be easier (exclude ou filter, and run just 3 computers)
i ran that on my machine, work without any problems...

```
$PCName = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties * |
        Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

$PCName[4..6] | % { Invoke-Command -ComputerName $_ -ScriptBlock {1} }
```